# How to create more than two classes in a single package in java?

Tags: java

Please help me here ,I'm stuck with a problem that how i can create multiple classes in a single package in java.
Two classes works fine, if we have and one class extends to another.
but i have more than two classes, than how i can create that?

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: you can create any number of classes in a single package in java . Please share your code in order to understand your problem

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to make 1 class extend many classes. This is illegal in Java since is doesn't support multiple inheritance like C++. But again, please clarify your question so that we can actually help.

Comment: You create classes, it’s that simple. Find this answer useless? Try asking a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need (say) 17 different classes, create 17 different source files, one per class.

Separation into source files is only necessary if the classes are public, but it's a useful structuring approach in any case.

Use the exact same 'package' declaration in each file.

That's all that is needed.